# Numbers $a$ that are the sum of the fractional parts $\{x^2\} + \{x\}$ for some $x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, fractional-part

Are there infinitely many rational numbers $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ with the following property:

> $\{x^2\}+\{x\}=a$ for infinitely many $x\in\mathbb{Q}^+$

Comment: Please add context to your question--where this question is from, what you have tried.  As it stands, your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Speaking only for myself, it would really help if you added an example of a number $a$ with its "matching" $x$. I will vote "Leave Open" but the others will probably say "Close."

Comment: @RobertSoupe How bout $0$ and $0$?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I should've said "a nontrivial example."

Comment: source: math olympiad problems or teaching materials, found somewhere in the internet, 
I don't remember the exact source, I have this unsolved for a long time
\\

example: for $a=0.99$ one can take $x=122.7$ matching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, for every number $a=1/n+1/n^2$ there are infinitely many $x$ with claimed property: let's take $x=kn+1/n$ for any $k\in\Bbb N$. Then $\{x\}=1/n$, $x^2=k^2n^2+2k+1/n^2, \{x^2\}=1/n^2$, $\{x^2\}+\{x\}=1/n^2+1/n=a$.

Comment: Yeah, I supposed that this problem only seems to be unreachable, but in fact one has to have one brilliant idea and it will be all. And you did it - thanks and congratulations :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  what is the maximum the left side can be?  If $x$ is a rational solution, can you find another one?